# Joda Date-Time: Capture Date time(UTC) and convert to byte/byte array

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I am writing an application in which I have to capture the current date time in UTC and it to the Header of an image file.

I am using Joda date-time. Now the requirement is to get the current date time in UTC and convert it to byte byte/byte array so that it can be stored as the hexadecimal values in header of image file.

What I have tried so far

```
DateTime date = new DateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).
                withChronology(ISOChronology.getInstanceUTC());
```

It is giving me this output:

```
2013-06-07T09:25:51.630Z
```

I dont know why there is T and z there in output.

Now I have to convert it to bytes/bytes array. But I am not getting how to do that.

Any Help?

**EDIT:**
As per the standard I am following they have given an example of result after converion

December 15,2005 at 17:35:19.000 ==> 07D5 0C 0F 11 23 13 0000Hex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DateTime date = new DateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).
>                   withChronology(ISOChronology.getInstanceUTC());

If all you want is UTC you can use plain

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

BTW, all computers actually use GMT rather than supporting UTC. e.g. no leap seconds.

> I don't know why there is T and z there in output.

ISO 8601 standard.

> Now I have to convert it to bytes/bytes array.

There are many different ways to do this. Can you say how you need the translation to be performed?

> As per the standard I am following they have given an example of result after converion
>   December 15,2005 at 17:35:19.000 ==> 07D5 0C 0F 11 23 13 0000Hex

Which standard you referring to?

If `07D5 0C 0F 11 23 13 0000` was the time in milli-seconds you would be in the year 1.1 trillion.

Comment: I am following ISO/IEC 19794-4:2011 Finger Image Standard. The example is in the same standard. I have to follow same and capture date time.

Comment: 07D5 0C 0F 11 23 13 0000 referring to December 15,2005 at 17:35:19.000

Comment: I don't know any more than the people who have answered this question before.  I don't think this than is used much so you might need to buy the original standard fro ISO.